# Image source unknown when url is returned from controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am new to Ui design and I am trying to write simple application using JSP and spring boot.
The idea is to get the Google QR code URL in the controller and return to JSP page:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%%7C0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth%3A%2F%2Ftotp%2FSpringRegistration%3Atest_user%3Fsecret%3DI2S5OTJXDG5NBWVY%26issuer%3DSpringRegistration
```

So, my controller looks like as below:

```
@GetMapping("/confirmRegistration")
public String confirmRegistration(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                  final Model model) {
    final User user = userService.getUser(token);
    String qrUrl = userService.generateQRUrl(user);
    log.info("QR URL: {}", qrUrl);
    model.addAttribute("qr_code", qrUrl);
    return "redirect:/qrcode";
}
```

My JSP looks like -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Confirm your account</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Scan following QR code.</label>
    <c:if test="${param.url != null}">
        <span> hi there </span>
        ${param.url}
    </c:if>
    <c:url value="${qr_code}" />
    <img src="${qr_code}" width=256 height=256 />
    <br />
    <img src="${param.qr[0]}"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it is not populating the image. UI page looks like below:
[image]

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: what does `log.info("QR URL: {}", qrUrl);` give ? does that giving correct value for n`qrUrl` ?

Comment: Yes, it prints the url and if I open that url in browser, I can see the QR code.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the issue is related to `return` statement. You should point a name of your jsp page that the model with image url is forwarded to. But before, you need to define and configure [`InternalResourceViewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-view-jsp)

For more info ([redirecting](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix) / [forwarding](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-redirecting-forward-prefix))